Why is my Javascript Carousel Starting On the Wrong Slide?
I was building a carousel for my portfolio and for some reason it is starting on the wrong slide. I am using html, css, and javascript. Everything looks good in terms of the content, but for some reason the carousel is starting on the wrong place and some of the content is not appearing so it feels like it's a javascript issue. But it's been driving me crazzzzyyyy
Here's what i tried:
<div class="carousel-container"> 
<button class="control-button-prev">‹</button> 
<div class="carousel-wrapper"> 
<div class="carousel-slide"> 
<img src="creative-book-ch1.png" alt="Chapter 1 Cover"> 
<div class="carousel-item"> 
<p class="caption"> [insert context]
</p> 
</div>
</div> 

^I repeated the above format for 11 different slides^
.carousel-container {
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden; 
} 

.carousel-wrapper { 
display: flex; 
width: 100%; 
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center; 
} 

.carousel-slide { 
flex: 0 0 100%; 
min-width: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center; 
padding: 10px; 
}

^the above is the CSS that I think could potentially be affecting it (although I think the real problem is in the javascript)
   <script> 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Selectors and initial setup
    const carouselContainer = document.querySelector(".carousel-wrapper"); 
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-slide");
    let currentIndex = 0; // Start at the first slide
    const totalItems = slides.length;

    // Log total slides and initial state
    console.log("Total slides:", totalItems);
    slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
        console.log(`Slide ${index} - Source: ${slide.querySelector("img").src}`);
    });

    function updateCarousel() {
        const offset = -(100 * currentIndex); // Offset calculation
        carouselContainer.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
        carouselContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}%)`;
        console.log(`Updating carousel - Current Index: ${currentIndex}, Offset: ${offset}%`);
    }

    document.querySelector(".control-button-next").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (currentIndex < totalItems - 1) { 
            currentIndex++;
            console.log("Next button clicked - New Index:", currentIndex);
            updateCarousel();
        }
    });

    document.querySelector(".control-button-prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (currentIndex > 0) { 
            currentIndex--;
            console.log("Previous button clicked - New Index:", currentIndex);
            updateCarousel();
        }
    });

    updateCarousel(); // Initial display
});
        </script> 


It starts on slide 6 on my website instead of slide 1 and I have 0 clue as to why

It's not easy to help you without a reproduceable example.  Strip your question down to the necessary code needed to reproduce the problem, and be sure to include the relevant HTML and CSS.

I'm relatively new to coding so I think that's probably one of the things I'm struggling with. this is the html format I'm using:  
‹




   (i don't have enough characters, but this the general format)

This is the general css /potential issue areas:
.carousel-container {position: relative;
overflow: hidden; } .carousel-wrapper {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
} .carousel-slide {
flex: 0 0 100%;
min-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
padding: 10px;
}

code is difficult to read in comments.  please add new information directly in the question using the edit feature.

okay thanks! I didn't know i could do that - will add it in now
